# appearance="xxforms:menu" don't work in 4.9

Tags: orbeon

Orbeon,

I upgrade my project to 4.9. but the appearance="xxforms:menu" is not display as the select not the menu. what should I do for my requirement.
following is my code

Comment: <xforms:select1 ref="xxforms:instance('NAVIGATION-INSTANCE')/TopMenuResource/SelectedURL"  appearance="xxforms:menu">
 <xforms:itemset  nodeset="xxforms:instance('NAVIGATION-INSTANCE')/TopMenuResource/TopMenuList//Menu">
 <xforms:label><xforms:output value="if (count(./Menu)&gt;0) then concat(./Label,' &#187;') else ./Label"/>
                                         </xforms:label>
                                        <xforms:value ref="LoadURL"/>
                                    </xforms:itemset>
                                </xforms:select1>

Comment: Your document http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/how-to/view/contextual-menu. My code worked in 3.7

Answer (score 0):

`xxforms:menu` and `xxforms:tree` are no longer available since [Orbeon Forms 4.8](http://blog.orbeon.com/2015/01/orbeon-forms-48.html).

They hadn't been maintained for a very long time, and YUI development has stopped, and since there was no apparent demand for those we had to make a choice. You could create a new XBL component doing this, though.